# CentOS Run Script when Ethernet Plug Events Occurs

Tags: shell-script, centos, network-interface

I want to run a bash or python script once when the ethernet cable is plugged in or out.

I am using CentOs 6.8;

- I write a script and save as "ifup-pre-local" into "/sbin", it works only when I restart the network service. When I unplug/plug the cable, there is nothing.